# Weird tikz / gnuplot / TeXShop issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, texshop, gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot under tikz to generate a graph; here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4.1, xscale=1.5, yscale=1.5] 
    \draw[blue, line width=2pt, samples=1000] plot[id=foo] 
        function{x**2} node[right] {$f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The gnuplot script is getting generated correctly (so, test.foo.gnuplot exists and looks right), but gnuplot is not getting invoked properly, which I can tell because test.foo.table doesn't exist. If I go into a terminal and navigate to my folder and manually invoke gnuplot on the auto-generated script, the table gets generated, and then tikz will correctly draw the graph on the next compile.

I started poking around in the console and in the logs, and here's the thing I noticed in the console that looks most pertinent:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))sh: gnuplot: command not found
```

Just in case this was a bash vs. sh thing, I manually invoked gnuplot in a sh terminal, and it worked fine, so that's not the problem either.

I'm using TeXShop 3.75 under Mac OS X 10.11. My command is:

```
pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape
```

My distribution information:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.24)
```

Ideas on what's maybe going on here?

Thanks!

EDIT: With the help of some people on /r/LaTeX, I figured out what the issue was. It turns out that TeXShop has its own little path setting buried deep in the preferences windows, and also that you can't seem to add more than one directory to that path setting. So, I just created a symbolic link to gnuplot in the directory that's set as the default path (/Library/TeX/texbin, if you're curious), and now everything works fine.

I'm adding TeXShop to the tag list, because this really ended up being a TeXShop issue, and I'm setting this question to "answered."

Comment: Welcome! Please post the part of the log relevant to the plot.

Comment: That is, there's nothing wrong with the code (although loading `pgf` is unneeded, since `tikz` loads it anyhow) and you clearly have `gnuplot` installed. So my guess is that it cannot be found when needed, but the log would tell you whether that's a correct guess or way off the mark.

Comment: My bet is that if you remove the `.gnuplot` and `.table` files and you rerun `pdflatex` from TeXShop, you'll find this line in the `.log`: `runsystem(gnuplot spencer.foo.gnuplot)...disabled (restricted)`

Comment: Try to start `TeXShop` from your Terminal.

Comment: Hi @cfr, here's the relevant log bits:
`\openout3 = \`reduce.foo.gnuplot'.`
`runsystem(gnuplot reduce.foo.gnuplot)...executed.`
`Package pgf Warning: Plot data file \`reduce.foo.table' not found. on input line 9.`
So, @egreg, nope, the --shell-escape appears to be working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[With the help of some people on /r/LaTeX](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/5rayz3/weird_shellescape_issue/), I figured out what the issue was. It turns out that TeXShop has its own little path setting buried deep in the preferences windows, and also that you can't seem to add more than one directory to that path setting. So, I just created a symbolic link to gnuplot in the directory that's set as the default path (/Library/TeX/texbin, if you're curious), and now everything works fine.

I'm adding TeXShop to the tag list, because this really ended up being a TeXShop issue, and I'm setting this question to "answered."

Comment: To set it as 'answered', click the grey tick at the top left of your answer to accept it.

Comment: Yeah, it had the 24-hour timeout. Sorry for any confusion. :)